# Expand \def value from optional default argument? - Bug in \oldacronym (glossaries v4.02) - first use not respected and funny effects?

Tags: glossaries, expansion, detokenize

> Edit: Bug only in glossaries v4.02. -> Update!
>
> `\edef\args{[#4]{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
>   \expandafter\newacronym\args%`
>
> may be a way to expand unexpaned args.

Is there a bug in the glossaries Package? Is there something like `\newcommand{\oldacronym}[4][\autoexpand\gls@label]{% ...` to fix this. Can `\detokenize` be used and if how?

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{glossaries}    
\makeglossaries

\oldacronym[ABC]{ABC}{ABC working}{description={foo}}
%\oldacronym[DEF]{DEF}{DEF working}{description={bar}}
\oldacronym{DEF}{DEF not working}{description={bar}}
\oldacronym[GHI]{GHI}{GHI not working}{description={baz}}
\oldacronym[JKL]{JKL}{JKL working}{description={faz}}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\ABC\\ \ABC\\ \ABC\\
\DEF\\ \DEF\\ \DEF\\
\GHI\\ \GHI\\ \GHI\\
\JKL\\ \JKL\\ \JKL\\

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Try commenting in and out the different definitions of \DEF and see.

From what I have debugged so far [`\gls@label`] doesn't seem to get properly expanded into #1 for `\newacronym[#4]{#1}{#2}{#3}` hence all oldacronym entries seem to share "\gls@label" literally as key instead of its value.

That is the definition of \oldacronym in [glossaries.sty](http://math.sut.ac.th/lab/software/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty)!

```
\newcommand{\oldacronym}[4][\gls@label]{%
  \def\gls@label{#2}%
  \newacronym[#4]{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \ifcsundef{xspace}%
  {%
    \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\@ifstar{\noexpand\Gls{#1}}{\noexpand\gls{#1}}%
    }%
  }%
  {%
    \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\@ifstar{\noexpand\Gls{#1}\noexpand\xspace}{%
      \noexpand\gls{#1}\noexpand\xspace}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

Is there something like `\newcommand{\oldacronym}[4][\autoexpand\gls@label]{% ...` or `\newacronym[#4]{\autoexpand{#1}}{#2}{#3}% ...` to fix this?

Wrong: [image: Wrong]
Correct: [image: Correct]

Comment: I see no difference when I switch the comment character (apart from “not” appearing and disappearing). Can you describe more precisely what's the problem? What version of `glossaries` are you using? I have (in the log file) `Package: glossaries 2014/11/22 v4.12 (NLCT)`

Comment: ad a) The problem is that only the first appearence of a glossary entry should show the longer version, on my machine it shows it multiple times if the optional argument is not provided. 
ad b) how can I find out the version of glossaries on MikTex? The package manager shows also 4.12 Date: 2014-12-22 22:00:01 ... so hum?

Comment: Look in the `.log` file in the same directory as your `.tex` file. Open it with any text editor.

Comment: Okay done, ... two screenshots and the version: (C:\Users\user_local\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\base\gloss
aries.sty
Package: glossaries 2013/12/05 v4.02 (NLCT)

Comment: You have an outdated version of `glossaries`. Update. Be sure to do it as administrator.

Comment: Thank you, could you anyway tell me if the solution below with `expandafter` can be used to expand all arguments for future situations? Also interesting is that MikTeX seems to have a different package repository for my admin_local and my user_local usernames ... funny!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a problem due to outdated software, solved by updating.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked a solution, but I'm not sure it's a clean one; also somthing like properly expanding `#1 in \newacronym[#4]{#1}{#2}{#3}% ...` would be much more elegant from my perspective.

```
\makeatletter
\def\ifemptyarg#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax % H. Oberdiek
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}

\renewcommand{\oldacronym}[4][]{%
  \ifemptyarg{#1}
  {%
    \def\gls@label{#2}%
    \newacronym[#4]{#2}{#2}{#3}%
  }
  {%
    \def\gls@label{#1}%
    \newacronym[#4]{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
  %
  \ifcsundef{xspace}%
  {%
    \expandafter\edef\csname \gls@label\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\@ifstar{\noexpand\Gls{\gls@label}}{\noexpand\gls{\gls@label}}%
    }%
  }%
  {%
    \expandafter\edef\csname \gls@label\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\@ifstar{\noexpand\Gls{\gls@label}\noexpand\xspace}{%
      \noexpand\gls{\gls@label}\noexpand\xspace}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This seems like to be better than with ineffective `\expandafter` commands.

Comment: What do you mean by ineffecive? - inefficient? At least the second solution is a lot shorter and the conditionals are avioded by having `#1` always declared ... isn't it?

Comment: In `\expandafter\edef\expandafter\args{[#4]{#1}{#2}{#3}}` the two `\expandafter` commands do absolutely nothing.

Comment: Well at least for v 4.02 this was necessary to solve the problem, I'll double test if can downgrade back ... Do you know how this can be done in MikTeX.

Comment: Found v4.02 in an [old rpm](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/6/idpl/26345012/dir/fedora_20/com/texlive-glossaries-svn32341.4.02-5.fc20.noarch.rpm)! So the two expandafter can go away. Learned something thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work, can someone explain me if this could be used as a general technique to expand all arguments before passing them on to another command?

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\oldacronym}[4][\gls@label]{%
  \def\gls@label{#2}%
  %
  \edef\args{[#4]{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
  \expandafter\newacronym\args%
  %
  \ifcsundef{xspace}%
  {%
    \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\@ifstar{\noexpand\Gls{#1}}{\noexpand\gls{#1}}%
    }%
  }%
  {%
    \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\@ifstar{\noexpand\Gls{#1}\noexpand\xspace}{%
      \noexpand\gls{#1}\noexpand\xspace}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```